# Virtual Motives Infinitely Divisible by Lefschetz Motive

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, virtual-motives

Let $K_0(Var_k)$ be the grothendieck group of the category of $k$-varieties, and call its elements virtual motives. $\mathbb{L}:=[\mathbb{A}^1_k]$ is called the Lefschetz motive. I think that if a virtual motive is divisible by arbitrarily high powers of $\mathbb{L}$, then it must be $0$. Is this true? If so, is there a proof of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an open problem. It's probably quite hard.

Comment: May I please have a reference for this?

Comment: One reference is Daniel Litt, "Symmetric powers do not stabilize", Remark 3. I do not know who first asked this question.

Comment: This is an important question for the motivic integration theory; so you may look at surveys on this subject.